# Error creating stored procedure with openjson

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My problem is the following: I use SQL Server 2017 Express, I have a variable of type `json` previously formatted, it runs normal in a normal query.

But when I create the stored procedure, I get an error and I really don't know how to solve it. I'd appreciate if can someone help me out of this trouble.

This is the code in a normal query

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  '
  {
    "varios":[{
    "name":"David",
    "cant":"291123",
     "number":"205893"
        },
        {
    "name":"pedro",
    "cant":"295523",
     "number":"206693"
        },
            {
    "name":"maria",
    "cant":"295523",
     "number":"206693"
        }
    ]
    }
' 
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.varios' )  
     WITH (   
              name varchar(200) '$.name' ,  
              cant    int     '$.cant',  
              number int '$.number' 
          ) ;
```

This returns the following result:

```
Name         cant       number
------------------------------
David       291123      205893
pedro       295523      206693
maria       295523      206693
```

But when I try to do the same thing in a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_pro
    @json NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @json =   
  '
  {
    "varios":[{
    "name":"David",
    "cant":"291123",
     "number":"205893"
        },
        {
    "name":"pedro",
    "cant":"295523",
     "number":"206693"
        },
            {
    "name":"maria",
    "cant":"295523",
     "number":"206693"
        }
    ]
    }
' 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.varios' )  
    WITH (
            nombre varchar(50) '$.name',  
            cantidad int '$.cant',  
            numero int '$.number' 
         );
END
```

I get the following error which I could not solve:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_prueba2, Line 29 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '$.name'.

I appreciate if someone knows how it can be solved or what step I have omitted

Comment: It works for me if I copy-paste your query into an SQL Server and execute it. Perhaps your local copy has some invalid control characters in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OPENJSON function is available only under compatibility level 130 or higher. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server can't find and run the OPENJSON function. Other JSON functions are available at all compatibility levels.

You can check compatibility level in the sys.databases view or in database properties. You can change the compatibility level of a database with the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

Compatibility level 120 may be the default even in a new Azure SQL Database.